# How to fix the trademark symbol causing "cp950" error when writing a file in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, unicode

I am extracting text from a webpage and writing the content into a file:

```
import requests
from inscriptis import get_text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get(r'http://www3.asiainsurancereview.com//News/View-NewsLetter-Article/id/42528/Type/eDaily/Technology-First-round-of-the-pre-launch-of-the-Ydentity-ICO-starts-today')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
html = soup.find(class_='article-wrap')
text = get_text(html.text)
print(text)

articleFile = open('test.txt', 'w')
articleFile.write(text)
articleFile.close()
```

It prints the content on screen just fine, but its giving a unicode error when writing the content into a file:

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-859d4647d5eb> in <module>()
     10 
     11 articleFile = open('test.txt', 'w')
---> 12 articleFile.write(text)
     13 articleFile.close()

UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp950' codec can't encode character '\u2122' in position 51: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Upon printing the content to the console, I saw there are some trademark (TM) symbols in the article. So, I tried doing this:

`text=text.encode("utf-8")`

but I still get an error, albeit a different one:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-3f30355ab29c> in <module>()
     12 text=text.encode("utf-8")
     13 
---> 14 articleFile.write(text)
     15 
     16 articleFile.close()

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

I have tried the following, but to no avail:

```
text = get_text(html.text)

from unidecode import unidecode
def remove_non_ascii(text):
    return unidecode(str(text, encoding = "utf-8"))

articleFile = open('test.txt', 'w')
articleFile.write(text)
articleFile.close()
```

It gives the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-ff7e6a098308> in <module>()
     20 
     21 
---> 22 articleFile.write(remove_non_ascii(text))
     23 
     24 articleFile.close()

<ipython-input-70-ff7e6a098308> in remove_non_ascii(text)
      9 from unidecode import unidecode
     10 def remove_non_ascii(text):
---> 11     return unidecode(str(text, encoding = "utf-8"))
     12 
     13 articleFile = open('test.txt', 'w')

TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

I also tried this:

```
if isinstance(text, str):
    text = text
else:
    text = text.decode(encoding)
    decoded = True

articleFile.write(text)
articleFile.close()
```

and this gives the original error (so, basically, it does nothing):

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-f0c817f013af> in <module>()
     20 
     21 
---> 22 articleFile.write(text)
     23 
     24 articleFile.close()

UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp950' codec can't encode character '\u2122' in position 51: illegal multibyte sequence
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to be to open the file to write to in binary mode, and then to encode the unicode characters:

```
articleFile = open('test.txt', 'wb')
text=text.encode("utf-8")
articleFile.write(text)
articleFile.close()
```

Apparently, Python can't write encoded unicode text into a file unless the file being written to is opened in binary mode.

Comment: Exactly, encoded text is of type `bytes`, which is binary data, so writing it to a binary stream makes sense, doesn't it? But you should have a look at the `encoding` parameter of the [`open()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), so you don't have to encode the strings yourself: `with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f: f.write(text)`. Less code – less bugs.